# integration of libraries in the project under different architectures

Tags: c#, dll

I have 2 questions:

1. How to include library .dll in project that after compile it will integrity in exe (not separate: exe and dll). Does it possible?
2. I have one library 2 versions: for x64 and x86. How to include this library (2 version) and "using" for each architecture appropriate version: x64 for 64 bit and x86 for 32 bit.

Comment: This is just a deployment problem, copying the right files.  Users like setup.exe, especially its uninstall feature.  It is just programmers that don't like them.  These questions have been asked many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to both questions is to [load the assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173101.aspx) at runtime.

Comment: I saw that. I didn't get it. Please, give example with dlls: example32.dll and example64.dll

Comment: @MaximDroy see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593916/import-external-dll-based-on-64bit-or-32bit-os)