Build For Any CPU And Load .dll Files Based on Architecture Encountered by App
My Visual Studio .Net Framework C# projects builds for Any CPU. But there is a dll file, WebView2Loader.dll, to be specific, that has the 32 bit and 64 bit versions. I referenced them in the build settings in the .csproj file thus:
<Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)bin\$(Configuration)\runtimes\win-x64\native\WebView2Loader.dll">
      <Link>WebView2Loader64\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
      <PublishState>Included</PublishState>
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Pack>false</Pack>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)bin\$(Configuration)\runtimes\win-x86\native\WebView2Loader.dll">
      <Link>WebView2Loader86\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
      <PublishState>Included</PublishState>
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Pack>false</Pack>
    </Content>

So that the WebView2Loader.dll file versions are copied to the appropriate directories. Now the question is, how and where do I set the conditions for my app to load the required version based on the architecture it is installed on?

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1197868/conditional-build-to-use-project-reference-or-pack

At runtime you want your Any CPU app to implicitly load the correct DLL, is that the question?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2594135/17034
